# Static table view cells seem to have the same data and cell selected index?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Basically I need two things to work with the cells in my view, a tap and a tap and hold gesture. I have the tap and hold gesture working like so:

```
-(void) longTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer= %@",gestureRecognizer);

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"longTap began");

        CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
        if (indexPath == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);

            switch (indexPath.row)
            {
                case 0:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 5;
                    break;
            }
        }

        UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MealPlannerRecipeTypeViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I need this gesture to set a value in a singleton class to a certain value depending on what row is selected. No matter what row is selected this value is always 0?! Can anyone tell me why?

Second part of the question is that one of my tableview delegates looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    RecipeInfo *recipeInfo = recipeInfoArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = recipeInfo.name;

    // Add long tap for the main tiles
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longTap:)];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Every row in my table view has the same information as the first one? Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want tell me simply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using reusable cells, and you've changed the textLabel inside the if() alloc-init block.

Move the `cell.textLabel.text` line out of the if() { } block right above `return cell;`

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = ...
}
    RecipeInfo *recipeInfo = recipeInfoArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel.text = recipeInfo.name;
    return cell;
}
```

EDIT: The above was for question 2.

The first question, about your gesture recognizer...looking at your code, you have

```
[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
```

But later you write

```
[myTable indexPathForRowAtPoint
```

Did you think to change `locationInView:self.tableView` to `locationInView:myTable`

Answer (score 0):

You set cell values only when you created it. The "dequeue" can return a already instantiated cell. I purpose that move if bracket.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Add long tap for the main tiles
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longTap:)];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];

    }
    RecipeInfo *recipeInfo = recipeInfoArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = recipeInfo.name;

    ...
```

Comment: You can set the gesture at the to creat cell